# How to efficiently compute disjointness with OWLAPI?

Tags: owl, owl-api

I'm profiling my application that is OWLAPI based and the only bottleneck I found was about computing **disjointness**.
I have to check if each class is disjoint from other classes and, if this is *asserted* or *inferred*.

It seems to be heavy to compute, because unlike for the equivalence which is based on the *Node* data structure (and it is efficient to retrieve data), the disjointness is based on the *NodeSet* in this way I'm forced to perform more loops.
This is the procedure I use:

```
private void computeDisjointness(OWLClass clazz) {

    NodeSet<OWLClass> disjointSetsFromCls = reasoner.getDisjointClasses(clazz);
    for (Node<OWLClass> singleDisjoinSet : disjointSetsFromCls) {
        for (OWLClass item : singleDisjoinSet) {
             for (OWLDisjointClassesAxiom disjAxiom : ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.DISJOINT_CLASSES)) {
                 if(disjAxiom.containsEntityInSignature(item))
                  {
                   //asserted
                  }
                  else
                  {
                  //derived
                  }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the bottleneck is given by the 3 for loops that slow down the application; moreover, the procedure *computeDisjointness* is executed for each class of the ontology.

Is there a more efficient way to get the disjointness and check if the axioms are asserted or derived?

Comment: what is the reason behind not using a reasoner? I mean, your approach is obviously incomplete in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple optimization is to move `ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.DISJOINT_CLASSES)` to the calling method, then pass it in as a parameter. This method returns a new set on each call, with the same contents every time, since you're not modifying the ontology. So if you have N classes you are creating *at least* N identical sets; more if many classes are actually disjoint.

Optimization number two: check the size of the disjoint node set. Size 1 means no disjoints, so you can skip the rest of the method.

Optimization 3: keep track of the classes you've already visited. E.g., if you have

```
A disjointWith B
```

your code will be called on `A` and cycle over `A` and `B`, then be called on `B` and repeat the computation.
Keep a set of visited classes, to which you add all elements in the disjoint node set, and when it's `B` turn you'll be able to skip the reasoner call as well. Speaking of which, I would assume the reasoner call is actually the most expensive call in this method. Do you have profiling data that says otherwise?

Optimization 4: I'm not convinced this code reliably tells you which disjoint axioms are inferred and which ones are asserted. You could have:

```
A disjointWith B
B disjointWith C
```

The reasoner would return `{A, B, C}` in response to asking for disjoints of `A`. You would find all three elements in the signature of a disjoint axiom, and find out that the reasoner has done no inferences. But the axioms in input are not the same as the axioms in output (many reasoners would in fact run absorption on the input axioms and transform them to an internal representation that is an axiom with three operands).
So, my definition of inferred and asserted would be that the set of nodes returned by the reasoner is the same as the set of operands of one disjoint axiom. To verify this condition, I would take all disjoint axioms, extract the set of operands and keep those sets in a set of sets. Then,

- for each class (and keeping in place the optimization to visit each class only once),

  - obtain the set of disjoint nodes (optimization here to not bother if there's only one class in the set),
  - transform it to a set of entities,
  - and check whether the set of sets created earlier contains this new set. 
    If yes, this is an asserted axiom; if not, it's inferred.